# Como mostrar en el html el valor que recibe una variable en typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Quiero pintar el valor que esta recibiento la variable numberTable en mi archivo html, pero no logro hacerlo y por consola si lo veo. Si me pueden ayudar, se los agradezco, les muestro mi codigo:

Este es el componente.html que tienes los botones de casa mesa:

```
<div class="btn-table-container">
  <button (click)="selectTable($event)" id="mesa01" class="btn-table" [routerLink]="['/', 'menu']">Mesa 01</button>
  <button (click)="selectTable($event)" id="mesa02" class="btn-table" [routerLink]="['/', 'menu']">Mesa 02</button>
  <button (click)="selectTable($event)" id="mesa03" class="btn-table" [routerLink]="['/', 'menu']">Mesa 03</button>
  <button (click)="selectTable($event)" id="mesa04" class="btn-table" [routerLink]="['/', 'menu']">Mesa 04</button>
  <button (click)="selectTable($event)" id="mesa05" class="btn-table" [routerLink]="['/', 'menu']">Mesa 05</button>
  <button (click)="selectTable($event)" id="mesa06" class="btn-table" [routerLink]="['/', 'menu']">Mesa 06</button>
</div>
```

Este es el componente.ts donde al presionar cada boton se obtiene el evento con el id de cada mesa :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-waiter-tables',
   templateUrl: './waiter-tables.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./waiter-tables.component.scss']
})
export class WaiterTablesComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  selectTable(event: any) {
     const idTable = event.target.id;
     console.log(idTable)
     this.dataService.tablesEvent$.emit(idTable)
  }
}
```

Este es el componente donde quiero obtener el numero de mesa

```
 numberTable: string = '';

//Aqui me suscribo al servicio
this.dataService.tablesEvent$.subscribe(numMesa => {
  this.numberTable = numMesa;
  console.log(this.numberTable); 
  console.log('numero de mesa es:', numMesa);
})
```

Este es el html donde quiero pintar cual fue el numero de mesa que guardo la variable

```
<div class="commensalDates">
    <div class="commensalNameDiv">
      <label for="commensal" class="commensalNameLabel">
        <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'user']"></fa-icon>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="commensalNameInput" class="form-control" (keyup)="changeCommensalName($event)"
        placeholder="Nombre cliente" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
    <label for="commensal" class="commensalTableLabel">Mesa N°: {{numberTable}}</label>

  </div>
```

Y este es el resultado: les muestro imagen
como pueden observar el numero de mesa esta vacio y deberia mostrar la mesa que seleccione, que en la consola se puede ver que fue la mesa 02
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay distintas formas de detectar el cambio  EventEmiter no esta pensado para servicios
[[EventEmiter](http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2017/05/comunicacion-servicio-componente-en-angular.html)][1](http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2017/05/comunicacion-servicio-componente-en-angular.html)

> No tiene  este problema  BehaviorSubject este es tanto un Observable como un observador  y lo
> podes llamar o modificar en cualquier parte del codigo counicando a
> los componentes y la vista podemos  vincular a tu string con un
> observable

```js
//data service
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';


idTable:String;
idTable$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
ngOnInit() {
  this.idTable$.subscribe(m=>console.log('idTable',m));}


 public escucha(): Observable<string> {
    return this.idTable$.asObservable();
}
public emite(idTable: string): void {
    this.idTable$.next(idTable);
}


   //tu codigo vinculandolo al servicio
     selectTable(event: any) {
     const idTable = event.target.id;
     console.log(idTable)
     this.dataService.emite(idTable)
     
     
// nos suscribimos con :
 this.dataService.escucha().subscribe(numMesa => {
  this.numberTable = numMesa;
  console.log(this.numberTable); 
  console.log('numero de mesa es:', numMesa);
})
```